# Saving and Restoring caret position for contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a `contentEditable` div, the `innerHTML` of which can be updated through AJAX while editing. The problem is that when you change the contents of the div it moves the cursor to the end of the div (or loses focus depending on the browser). What is a good cross-browser solution to store caret position before changing `innerHTML` and then to restore it?

Answer (score 42):

back to 2016 :)
After I came across solutions here and they did not suit me, because my DOM was replaced completely after each typing. I've done more research and come with a simple solution that saves the cursor by character's position that works **perfect** for me.

The idea is very simple.

1. find the length of characters before caret and save it.
2. change the DOM.
3. using `TreeWalker` to walk just on `text nodes` of `context node` and counting characters  until we got the right `text node` and the position inside it

Two edge case:

1. content removed completely so there is no `text node`:
   *so*: move the cursor to the start of the context node
2. there is less content than the `index` pointed on :
   *so*: move the cursor to the end of the last node

```js
function saveCaretPosition(context){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.setStart(  context, 0 );
    var len = range.toString().length;

    return function restore(){
        var pos = getTextNodeAtPosition(context, len);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        var range = new Range();
        range.setStart(pos.node ,pos.position);
        selection.addRange(range);

    }
}

function getTextNodeAtPosition(root, index){
    const NODE_TYPE = NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT;
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NODE_TYPE, function next(elem) {
        if(index > elem.textContent.length){
            index -= elem.textContent.length;
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
        }
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    });
    var c = treeWalker.nextNode();
    return {
        node: c? c: root,
        position: index
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.1/prism.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/PrismJS/prism/gh-pages/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  *{
    outline: none
    }
</style>  
<h3>Edit the CSS Snippet </H3>
<pre>
    <code class="language-css" contenteditable=true >p { color: red }</code>
</pre>

<script >
  var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];
  
  code.addEventListener('input',function () {
        var restore = saveCaretPosition(this);
        Prism.highlightElement(this);
        restore();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What if you have line breaks and other formatting elements within the content editable element?

Comment: you mean like <br> of <span></span>? it  still should work . that code build for richtext editor that change elements around the cursor when user writing

Comment: I have a content editable with breaks and such and it works. If you use it for an undo function, store the last keypress in a onKeyDown handler and use `range.setStart(pos.node ,pos.position-(lastKeypress == 13 ? 0:1));` to prevent the cursor going on a walk :-)

Comment: I actually have the same question as @pelican_george - your approach works very well, but it does not work with line breaks. As soon as your insert a line break, the cursor stays on the first line (even thou the new line has been created).

Have a look at the jsfiddle with your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/80ovoxr9

I couldn't the line breaks to work unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I check it and find a little bug in the loop. but there another bug into `Prism`.  I fixed the loop bug (https://jsfiddle.net/80ovoxr9/10/]. ( Shift  + Enter help you get down a line)

Comment: What about restoring a selection, not only a caret position?

Comment: user selecting some text and then continue to write stuff, and he expect the selecting area remains ? anyway I guess you can create two range object one for the start position and one for the end position and use them to restore the selection range

Comment: @perymimon That saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: I get a bug with this script that causes the cursor to jump to the beginning when I put it at the end and enter a character. The solution is as simple as changing to `index > elem.textContent.length` and `position: index`, but I can't edit the answer because the queue is full.

Comment: 'lastNode' is assigned a value but never used

Comment: @Motla Thanks :), it clean it up a bit, probably stay there from a previous version

Comment: This answer is so close to perfect, but in still has some enter key/line break issues. Shift + enter doesn't work on firefox. Also adding line breaks to the end of the string  doesn't work in firefox. Also, in Chrome, is it possible to make "enter" work in the same way as "shift + enter"?

Comment: thanks. can you know how the reason for this and how to solve it? I will update my The reason

Comment: Seem like changing <code> to display inline-block help a bit with line-break.

Comment: If anyone interested anymore, I have an approach that will work for line breaks and formatting element.

Comment: Anyone using this in react/nextjs? this works for me, but have a side effect..

its selecting/highlighting all the text before the caret.. its weird because in the snippet above it doesnt show

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an ancient thread but I thought I would provide an alternative non-library solution

http://jsfiddle.net/6jbwet9q/9/

Tested in chrome, FF, and IE10+  Allows you to change, delete and restore html while retaining caret position/selection.

**HTML**

```
<div id=bE contenteditable=true></div>
```

**JS**

```
function saveRangePosition()
  {
  var range=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var sC=range.startContainer,eC=range.endContainer;

  A=[];while(sC!==bE){A.push(getNodeIndex(sC));sC=sC.parentNode}
  B=[];while(eC!==bE){B.push(getNodeIndex(eC));eC=eC.parentNode}

  return {"sC":A,"sO":range.startOffset,"eC":B,"eO":range.endOffset};
  }

function restoreRangePosition(rp)
  {
  bE.focus();
  var sel=window.getSelection(),range=sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var x,C,sC=bE,eC=bE;

  C=rp.sC;x=C.length;while(x--)sC=sC.childNodes[C[x]];
  C=rp.eC;x=C.length;while(x--)eC=eC.childNodes[C[x]];

  range.setStart(sC,rp.sO);
  range.setEnd(eC,rp.eO);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range)
  }

function getNodeIndex(n){var i=0;while(n=n.previousSibling)i++;return i}
```

Comment: This looks as though it's converting each selection range boundary to a path and back again. This is a great approach so long as the structure of the DOM is the same before and after the `innerHTML` changes, which isn't guaranteed to be true.

Comment: Is it possible to fix this code for multiple contenteditable divs? So that I can select, lets say, 1 of 3 div contenteditable, and then retrive the position of where I want to insert.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: bE is not defined

Answer (score 9):

**Update: I've ported Rangy's code to a standalone Gist:**

https://gist.github.com/timdown/244ae2ea7302e26ba932a43cb0ca3908

**Original answer**

You could use [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy), my cross-browser range and selection library. It has a [selection save and restore module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Selection-Save-Restore-Module) that seems well-suited to your needs.

The approach is not complicated: it inserts marker elements at the beginning and end of each selected range and uses those marker elements to restore the range boundaries again later, which could be implemented without Rangy in not much code (and you could even adapt [Rangy's own code](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/src/modules/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js)). The main advantage of Rangy is support for IE <= 8.

Comment: Fantastic. I had some trepidation about using a random library from some guy on SO, but it did what I wanted in 2 lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: @thedayturns: That's the correct attitude to have, so I don't blame you :) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @TimDown Does Rangy support multiple contenteditable divs? Like, saving position of caret over three different divs. Reason being, I want to use 1 editor for 3 different fields.

Comment: I not sure how that approach can work if i replace completely the whole div's content

Comment: @perymimon: No, it wouldn't. I'd use a character offset-based approach instead in that case.

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry for asking here, but is there a standalone version of the save / restore module that will not require the Rangy core ?

Comment: I'm essentially looking for two functions: "save_range": to insert invisible span elements at current selection start and end (or one at caret). and "restore_range": that will change the spans back into a selection. nothing much more than that.

Comment: @Norman: I ported Rangy's code to a standalone Gist: https://gist.github.com/timdown/244ae2ea7302e26ba932a43cb0ca3908. Obviously you can cut the selection stuff out if you like, but I left it in in case it was useful to anyone else.