# How to make the element textarea automatically color substrings?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What's the best way to have a `<textarea>` where you can write and it automatically colors the word `red` with the color red?

It should color it even if it's not surrounded by spaces.
So, for example, it should still work on the text `I ate tha'red-meat` and on the word `reddit`.

[This](http://www.morewords.com/contains/red/) is a perfect place to find words with `red` in it.

I have the following code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  background-color: GhostWhite;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried the css rule: `color: red;` ?

Comment: @Shilly - I don't want to color everything red, only the substring/word `red`.

Comment: not an easy task :) ... since you want to get `red` from `reddit`

Comment: Wait, do you want all the instances of the string 'red' to be colored red? I'm not sure that is possible inside a textarea. If you'd replace the text area with a div, you could easily find all substrings and wrap them in a span with styling red.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot customize text inside `textarea`, but you can simulate a textarea with a div with `contenteditable=true`, then you customize your text inside it

Comment: Just to clarify, mplungjan edited my question but the `<textarea>` isn't the same size as in that code snippet.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - Would it be a big difference if it was only `red` surrounded by spaces?

Comment: @user7393973 - please edit your own code then :)

Comment: @user7393973 : not possible with textarea

Comment: You want that this happens while typing, or on blur or some other time?

Comment: @mplungjan - I don't know why but it just doesn't get the 100% size on the code snippet. I couldn't figure it out why, that's why I didn't made one in the original question.

Comment: @baao - Automatically, if the content changes, have the substrings `red` colored.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - What about without a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @user7393973 : yes it's possible

Comment: @PranavCBalan - How?

Comment: @Shilly - Easly, could you show me how exactly?

Comment: @Pipe - How would I customize my text inside the `<div>`?

Comment: @user7393973 : I'd added an answer with partial output.... trying to make it perfect

Comment: @PranavCBalan - Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why did someone downvoted this question, did I made something wrong? Could he/she please explain in a comment so I don't do it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with `textarea`, instead use a `contenteditable` span(`span` is suggested to avoid problem with entering `<`) and wrap the color substring by using the span.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');

div.addEventListener('input', function() {
    // get the current position
    var pos = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(this);
  // get all word in the content  
  this.innerHTML = this.innerText.replace(/\w+/g, function(m) {
    // create a temporary span element
    var temp = document.createElement('span');
    // set current word as color
    temp.style.color = m;
    // check color is valid by rechecking the proeprty
    if (temp.style.color) {
      // if valid color then replace with temp elements html after setting content
      temp.innerHTML = m;
      return temp.outerHTML;
    }
    // else return the word itself
    return m;
  })
  // set caret position
  setCaretPosition(this, pos);
})



// following code is copied from following question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139475/restore-cursor-position-after-changing-contenteditable

function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
  var caretOffset = 0;
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel;
  if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = sel.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return caretOffset;
}

function setCaretPosition(element, offset) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  //select appropriate node
  var currentNode = null;
  var previousNode = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    //save previous node
    previousNode = currentNode;

    //get current node
    currentNode = element.childNodes[i];
    //if we get span or something else then we should get child node
    while (currentNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
      currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[0];
    }

    //calc offset in current node
    if (previousNode != null) {
      offset -= previousNode.length;
    }
    //check whether current node has enough length
    if (offset <= currentNode.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
  //move caret to specified offset
  if (currentNode != null) {
    range.setStart(currentNode, offset);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="div">sss</span>
```

**NOTE :** For position retaining code is copied from: [Restore cursor position after changing contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139475/restore-cursor-position-after-changing-contenteditable)

---

**UPDATE :** In case you just want to replace `red` within any word then you can do :

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');

div.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var pos = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(this);
  // get all red subtring and wrap it with span
  this.innerHTML = this.innerText.replace(/red/g, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>')
  setCaretPosition(this, pos);
})



// following code is copied from following question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139475/restore-cursor-position-after-changing-contenteditable

function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
  var caretOffset = 0;
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel;
  if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = sel.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return caretOffset;
}

function setCaretPosition(element, offset) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  //select appropriate node
  var currentNode = null;
  var previousNode = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    //save previous node
    previousNode = currentNode;

    //get current node
    currentNode = element.childNodes[i];
    //if we get span or something else then we should get child node
    while (currentNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
      currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[0];
    }

    //calc offset in current node
    if (previousNode != null) {
      offset -= previousNode.length;
    }
    //check whether current node has enough length
    if (offset <= currentNode.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
  //move caret to specified offset
  if (currentNode != null) {
    range.setStart(currentNode, offset);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="div" style="width:100%;display:block">sss</span>
```

**NOTE :** This solution is holds some problem related to newline since the content is HTML and where newline doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: That's a good start, but it seems to have some issues. It doesn't work when `red` isn't surrounded by spaces and it keeps changing the caret's position.

Comment: It's causing the same errors as some other answers. In that code snippet, `red` has to be surrounded by spaces to work and it keeps changing the caret's position when writing or selecting (using the arrow keys on the keyboard and shift for selecting).

Comment: @user7393973 : but for getting color from a string is really hard for ex : `reddit` ....

Comment: I think it's the most closest answer to what I want there is at the moment. Still, can you make it color `red` that isn't surrounded by spaces in both sides?

Comment: Now I can see that. Don't know how do people build code editors with multiple keywords in it. This is hard!

Comment: What I mean is, it won't color `red` in the examples `I ate tha'red-meat` and `reddit`.

Comment: @user7393973 in that which portion need to be colored ?

Comment: I only want `red` to be colored, nothing more. I'm just saying it should still color `red` when in "`red`dit".

Comment: Loving the way this is going, can you just make it multiple lines instead of one line?

Comment: When I try on a file and not on the code snippet, I get a [console error](http://i.imgur.com/ePs2gQd.png).

Comment: @user7393973 : you are missing id to the div :)

Comment: @user7393973 : you need to place script after the element... or load after elements are loaded

Comment: That solved it, but now when I write `<`, it deletes everything foward, unless it finds a `>` where it stops deleting. Anyway to solve that?

Comment: @user7393973 : use &lt;

Comment: I would prefer not to, but even if that was an option, it gets the caret's position wrong and on the next change of the `<div>`'s value, it will still delete everything forward of it and stop if it finds a `>`. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134795/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-user7393973).

Comment: @user7393973 : use `span` , I will add detail explanation on tommorrow....

Comment: I will try to continue this on Monday. Weekend is gaming time.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a contenteditable div, match any red that doesn't have a `>` right before it, and replace that red with : `"$1<span class='specialColor'>red</span>&zwnj;"` The zero-width non-joiner character at the end is used as a delimiter for the span.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var re = /([^\>])red/;
  var split = this.innerHTML.replace(re, "$1<span class='specialColor'>red</span>&zwnj;");
  this.innerHTML = split;
  placeCaretAtEnd(this);
})

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  background-color: GhostWhite;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.specialColor {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></div>
```

DISCLAIMER:

The placeCaretAtEnd() method is taken from this SO answer:[contenteditable, set caret at the end of the text (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/3993662)

Comment: That's close but at some points, it just makes all the text red. Also keeps changing the caret's position in the div which almost prevents writing (you can change it back with the mouse). If you start by typing just `red`, it doesn't colors the it.

Comment: Which browser are you using @user7393973

Comment: What you describe doesn't happen here... @user7393973, using chrome latest

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you give me an example text you are writing? @user7393973

Comment: Another problem I found is when you delete one of the red characters and break the substring `red`, the rest still stays red.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add partial styles to text inside an editable input area like `input` or `textarea`. It is considered as a single block of text and can only be styled as a whole.

But, the desired effect can be simulated by clever positioning of styled `span` elements.

There is one such project that provides on the go text highlighting. Check them out: [Code Mirror Project](https://codemirror.net/)

I've used codemirror on one of my personal projects. You should take a look at it too. [See the editable pane on the left](http://coderpad-clone.herokuapp.com/ad/vish)

Comment: I currently cannot check that external link because my internet connection doesn't allow as it has security limitations. Could you please make an effort to provide me a working example? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @user7393973 There is a working example here http://coderpad-clone.herokuapp.com/ad/vish

Comment: I know there's multiple working code editors out there that do the trick. What I was asking was the simplest code to do that and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm not happy about is how it handles line breaks and tabs.
It's a tiny bit more complex than only replacing red, but this way you can highlight any word in any color and probably even mix several of these on the same element, so the functions used are reusable.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #myTextarea {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        min-height: 50px;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .hl-red {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myTextarea" contenteditable>Test string</div>
<script>
var createHighlighter = function createHighlighter( word ) {
    // Let's create a reusable function that can highlight any word.
    // You call this function providing the word you want highlighted.
    // Then this returns a function that will insert some html spans around each instance of the word.
    // You can the call the returned function with any string to get the string saturated with the span tags.
    return function highlight( str ) {
        // We split on the word we want to highlight, so our array contains all the non-highlighted chunks.
        // Since we can call the function multiple times in a row, we will usually want to remove the previous highlights, so we don't double-highlight it.
        // This can be easily done with a simple global replace regex.
        var chunks;
        if (str === '<br>') return '';
        else {
            chunks = str.replace(/\<span\sclass="hl-red"\>/g, '').replace(/\<\/span\>/g, '').split(word);
            // Then we add the non-highlighted text + the <span> + the highlighted word.
            return chunks.reduce(function( html, chunk, index ) {
                html += chunk;
                // Add the highlighted word, except for the last chunk, since that's just the end of the string.
                if ((index + 1) !== chunks.length) html += '<span class="hl-red">' + word + '</span>';
                return html;
            }, '');
        }
    };
};

var wordToHighlight = 'red';

var highlightRed = createHighlighter( wordToHighlight );

var highlightArea = function highlightArea( event ) {
    event.target.innerHTML = highlightRed( event.target.innerHTML );
};

document.querySelector('#myTextarea').addEventListener('keyup', highlightArea);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it not change the caret's position?

Comment: That's less trivial than the highlighting, so I would refer to baao's answer concerning the caret.

Comment: baao's answer isn't currently working. If you write `red` and then delete the middle `e`, the `rd` stays with the color red.

Comment: If you combine the best parts from all the answers you got, you'll have it fully working. I prefer my version of the highlighting, since it allows any sequence of characters that isnt `</span>` or `<span class="hl-red">` and it doesn't suffer from backspace issues with words aprtially highlighted. But I can't get my version of the caret position to work, so I'm going to give up. Was a nice distraction. :)

Comment: You gave it a good try I must admit that. This got much attention and competition, and I will accept the answer of who gets it fully working, but right now, I think most gave up as it's to complicated. I will see what I can do...