# Prevent editable div's behavior when typing certain characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code taken from [Pranav C Balan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan)'s answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026254/how-to-make-the-element-textarea-automatically-color-substrings):

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');

div.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var pos = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(this);
  // get all red subtring and wrap it with span
  this.innerHTML = this.innerText.replace(/red/g, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>')
  setCaretPosition(this, pos);
})



// following code is copied from following question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139475/restore-cursor-position-after-changing-contenteditable

function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
  var caretOffset = 0;
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel;
  if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = sel.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return caretOffset;
}

function setCaretPosition(element, offset) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  //select appropriate node
  var currentNode = null;
  var previousNode = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    //save previous node
    previousNode = currentNode;

    //get current node
    currentNode = element.childNodes[i];
    //if we get span or something else then we should get child node
    while (currentNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
      currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[0];
    }

    //calc offset in current node
    if (previousNode != null) {
      offset -= previousNode.length;
    }
    //check whether current node has enough length
    if (offset <= currentNode.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
  //move caret to specified offset
  if (currentNode != null) {
    range.setStart(currentNode, offset);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="div" style="width:100%;display:block">sss</span>
```

It has a editable `<div>` where the user can input and it automatically colors the word `red` as red just like some code editors color key words like HTML tags, strings, functions, etc.
Type "red" and you will understand what I mean.

The issue I'm having is, when I type "<", it deletes all the characters in front of it unless it finds a ">" where it will stop. Another error happens if you type "&#1" (or any other number instead of 1 really).

Any ideia on how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: You're setting `innerHTML` to the raw text.

You need to either set it to the original HTML (which may duplicate tags) or HTML-escape the text.

Comment: How would I go about to do that?

Comment: Could I know the reason for the downvote? Only that way that I can try to prevent doing it again in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the person who upvoted. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into this problem because you're expecting the user to be able to input HTML-like entities such as `<xyz...` or `&#123;` but *don't want to parse that input as HTML*, but at the same time, you're yourself putting html elements **in the same div** and you want that *to be parsed as HTML*. So there are two ways you can go about this:

1. Keep the input and presentation separate. So user can input anything, which you'll sanitize and display in an output box.
2. Or... change the `addEventListener` function:

   ```
   div.addEventListener('input', function() {
     var pos = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(this);
     var userString = sanitizeHTML(this.innerText);

     // get all red subtring and wrap it with span
     this.innerHTML = userString.replace(/red/g, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>')
     setCaretPosition(this, pos);
   })
   ```

This would work in most scenarios, but it'd break (badly) if you're expecting user to input HTML too, for example `<span class="red" style="color: red">red</span>` would become horribly mutilated. Other than that, you're good to go. Get sanitizeHTML from here: https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html