# Recording and restoring the position of the caret within a contenteditable div using textangular

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, contenteditable, cursor-position

I've seen a lot of code snippets detailing how to get and set the caret position within a contenteditable div but I cannot get it to work in my case:

I am using a WYSIWYG text editor (textAngular). I have included functionality for the user to insert a cross-reference at the cursor position. They click a button, which opens up a dialog box for them to make selections from, which in turn will insert a html node at the current cursor position.

The location of the cursor may be within child nodes within the div such as p tags and/or other formatting tags.

My issue is that the current cursor position is lost when the dialog gains focus. I have tried storing the caret position (node and offset) in memory before opening the dialog but whatever I try the caret position always returns to the start of the div. I've tried all the code snippets I can find on stackoverflow but none of them work. I assume I am missing something.

Comment: I can see this has already been down-voted. It's very possible the question may not be clear to people or I may have missed something obvious, so if this is the case, please leave a comment here and I will correct it. If you feel this question has already been answered then please direct me to the answer and I will remove this question. Simply down-voting it without a reason is just unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: On second thoughts, your issue is probably that when you click the button the content editable looses focus and hence the selection is lost. We handle this as so in textAngular: `toolElement.attr('unselectable', 'on');`

Best solution for this is to use rangy instead of roll-your-own (required in textAngular ^1.3.0).

You've probably been down voted due to this being very similar to SO questions about "save and restore" caret position in content-editables e.g. [Saving and Restoring caret position for contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576694/saving-and-restoring-caret-position-for-contenteditable-div)

In the case of textAngular we've dealt with this issue multiple times and we have some shortcuts and helpers built into the TA (textAngular) toolbar tools.
Have a look at any of the issues here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/search?q=modal&type=Issues

If you have TA specific questions it's often best to look through the 500+ issues on the github repository. Chances are something similar has been attempted before.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: [Saving and Restoring caret position for contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576694/saving-and-restoring-caret-position-for-contenteditable-div/38479462)

Modified to your use case. When the combo `ctrl + i` is pressed a popup appears. You interact with the popup and press the close button, and then the cursor position is returned to it's original.

Without any other code this is what I had to go on.
I used jquery to make coding the example less verbose, but this also works without jquery.

```js
  function getRestorePosition(context) {
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      range.setStart(  context, 0 );
      var len = range.toString().length;
      
      return function restore(){
          var pos = getTextNodeAtPosition(context, len);
          selection.removeAllRanges();
          var range = new Range();
          range.setStart(pos.node, pos.position);
          selection.addRange(range);

      }
  }
  function getTextNodeAtPosition(root, index){
      var lastNode = null;

      var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function next(elem) {
          if(index > elem.textContent.length){
              index -= elem.textContent.length;
              lastNode = elem;
              return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
          }
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
      });
      var c = treeWalker.nextNode();
      return {
          node: c ? c: root,
          position: c? index:  0
      };
  }
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').on('keydown',function(e) {
     if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 73) {
        
        var popup = $('#popup');
        var restore = getRestorePosition(e.target);
        popup.show();
        popup.find('button').one('click',function() {
           popup.hide();
           restore();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     }
  });
```

```css
#popup {
   position:absolute;
   background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.8);
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   top:0px;
   display:none;
   color:white;
   text-align:center;
   padding:0px;200px;
   font-size:3em;
}
[contenteditable="true"] {
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">
   How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood
</div>
<div id="popup">
   A wood chuck could chuck as much wood as a woodchuck could chuck!<BR/>
   <button>close</button>
</div>
```