# How to insert HTML at caret position after restoring it

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

Currently i am writing an editor that is supposed to insert HTML at the caret position. This is supposed to happen after a choice has been made in the context menu.

Because opening the context menu removes the caret i'm saving it as following

```js
this.range = caret.cloneRange();
```

After the choice has been made i'm restoring the caret position and inserting html as following

```js
const sel = window.getSelection()!;
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(this.range);
const node = document.createTextNode(text);
range!.insertNode(node);
```

Unfortunately this causes the following error

```
HierarchyRequestError: The operation would yield an incorrect node tree.
```

Is there any way i can save and restore the caret position and insert html after that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving and Restoring caret position for contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576694/saving-and-restoring-caret-position-for-contenteditable-div)

Comment: There are other similar answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181700/125981

Comment: If those or similar do not answer your question please provide more detail including HTML and JavaScript  IN the question to provide more details and reproduce the problem right here.